# Repeat Nightwatch test automatically

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

Does anyone know a way I can automatically rerun a Nightwatch test a set number of times?

I have the following code:

```
module.exports = {
  'Log into system - create order': function (client) {
    client
      .url('XXXX')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.title('Reach - Log in')
      .assert.visible('#UserName')
      .setValue('#UserName', 'XXXX')
      .assert.visible('#Password')
      .setValue('#Password', 'XXXX')
      .assert.visible('input[value="Login"]')
      .click('input[value="Login"]')
      .waitForElementVisible('img.test', 1000)
      .assert.visible('li[title="XXXX"] a[tabindex="5"]')
      .click('li[title="Sales"]')
      .assert.cssClassPresent('li[title="XXXX"]', 'active')
      .click('a[href="/Quotes/Add"]')
      .waitForElementVisible('#s2id_CustomerId_Remote', 1000)
      .click('#s2id_CustomerId_Remote')
      .assert.visible('#s2id_autogen2_search')
      .setValue('#s2id_autogen2_search', 'bik')
      .waitForElementVisible('.select2-highlighted', 1000)
      .click('.select2-highlighted')
      .waitForElementVisible('#customerNotes', 1000)
      .click('#s2id_ProductId_Remote')
      .assert.visible('#s2id_autogen3_search')
      .setValue('#s2id_autogen3_search', '123XP')
      .pause(5000)
      .assert.visible('.select2-highlighted')
      .click('.select2-highlighted')
      .pause(5000)
      .assert.visible('.ui-sortable > tr')
      .setValue('#Quote_PONumber', 'abc123')
      .click('input[value="Create Order"]')
      .waitForElementVisible('.ac-order-number', 1000)
      .assert.visible('a[data-value="abc123"]')
      .pause(5000)
      .end()
  }
}
```

rather than `.end()` the test I'd like to `.rerun()` the test say 30 times. I can't see an option to do this anywhere in the docs.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap your commands in a `client.perform()` and a for loop

```
client.perform(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < 29; i++) { 
      client
        .url('XXXX')
        .
        .
        .
        .end();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a little of async iteration logic and `client.perform()` function :

```
module.exports = {
  'Log into system - create order': function (client) {
    var currentIteration = 0,
        iterationCount = 30;

    function runTest() {
      client
        .url('XXXX')

        // ... YOUR CODE HERE, WITHOUT .end()

        .perform(function() {
          if (++currentIteration < iterationCount) {
            return runTest();
          }

          client.end(); // After passing 30 iterations end the session
        });
    }

    runTest();
  }
};
```

Comment: @akm you could suggest an improvement of the existing answer instead of posting a different iteration of the same.

Comment: @StratosIon with all respect, the code you provided absolutely different compared to my example, and won't work at all since you're trying synchronously iterate over asynchronous code

Comment: @akm unless you have tried it locally and I'm doing something else that works, how else can you justify your claim?

Comment: @StratosIon just try and run it. `.end()` invocation will end the session after the first iteration. Also, `client.perform()` in your case is redundant, since you can put your for-loop right in the test method body. Regarding the loop, if for some reason, you'll need index of current iteration during the test, it would always be 28, however in order to fix that you can just put `let` before `i` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat he test with different inputs ? then you can do something like this

```
module.exports = {
  "Login Fail Cases": function(browser) {
    let dataSet = [
      { username: "madhus", pass: "madhus" },
      { username: "admin", pass: "admin" }
    ];

   //will run for 2 times as length of dataset is 2
    dataSet.forEach(function(data) {
      browser
        .url("https://localhost:3000/")
        // you tests here
    }, this);

    // note: end the test outside the loop once all tests are executed
    browser.end();
  }
};
```